# Algorithm that solves sudoku with bit operators

Tags: c, algorithm

I am studying an algorithm, the point is that I find it hard to understand as you isolate the exact number in the required position without the need (as I see it) an exhaustive search as is common in this type of algorithm, here the code :

```
int trycell(int *x, int pos)
{
    int row = pos / 9;
    int col = pos % 9;
    int i, j, used = 0;

    if (pos == 81)
        return 1;
    if (x[pos])
        return trycell(x, pos + 1);

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + col] - 1);

    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        used |= 1 << (x[row * 9 + j] - 1);

    row = row / 3 * 3;
    col = col / 3 * 3;

    for (i = row; i < row + 3; i++)
        for (j = col; j < col + 3; j++)
            used |= 1 << (x[i * 9 + j] - 1);

    for (x[pos] = 1; x[pos] <= 9; x[pos]++, used >>= 1)
    {

        if (!(used & 1) && trycell(x, pos + 1))
            return 1;
    }
    x[pos] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually it does do an exhaustive search, but slightly less exhaustive than "fully". It marks off the numbers used in the same row/col/square and then doesn't try those for this cell, because that would fail for obvious reasons.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I just want to understand how the algorithm works

Comment: What part do you have a problem understanding?  Is it the bit shifting?

Comment: Exactly that's the part I do not understand apparently the variable "used" serves to store the existing elements of binary form

Comment: The code is marking whether a given number has been used in the current row, column or 'sub grid' by setting bits in the int `used` in the position corresponding to the number (the -1 is because we're 'indexing' the bits from 0).

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/solving-sudoku-using-bitwise-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

Used is a bitmask containing 9 bits, one for each of the numbers. For example, if used is 100111000 (in binary), that means that somewhere in the cells of the same row/column/sector as the current cell, the numbers 9,6,5,4 have been set (each bit corresponds to a number with the leftmost bit being 9 and the rightmost one being 1).

The way used is set is like this:

```
used |= 1 << (x[index] - 1);
```

First, `x[index]` is the contents of some cell on the board, which is either 0 for an empty cell or 1..9 if the cell is filled in.  So `x[index]-1` is -1 for an empty cell, or 0..8 for a filled in cell.

For an empty cell, 1 << -1 equals 0.  So `used |= 0;` does not change used.

For a filled in cell, 1 << (n-1) is some bit in the bitmask.  Suppose the filled in cell had a 5 in it.  Then (1 << 4) equals 10000 (in binary) or 0x10 (in hex).  `used |= 0x10` sets that bit in used (or leaves it set if it was already set) without affecting the other bits.  So if used was 100000000 beforehand, it will be 100010000 afterwards.

So the last part is this:

```
for (x[pos] = 1; x[pos] <= 9; x[pos]++, used >>= 1)
{
    if (!(used & 1) && trycell(x, pos + 1))
        return 1;
}
```

What this loop is doing is:

1. The loop inserts the numbers 1..9 into the empty cell one at a time.
2. After inserting a number into the cell, it checks if `used` indicates that there was already that number in a row/col/sector.  This is the `!(used & 1)` part of the if statement.  If the number already appeared, then we can't use this number in this cell because it would cause a duplicate.  So it will fail the if and go on to the next number.
3. If `used` indicated that the number had not appeared already, then it recurses into `trycell(x, pos+1)`.  This means that we have filled in this cell with a possible number and we want to recursively (and brute forcefully) move on to the next cell to see if there are any possible solutions using this cell with this number.
4. If the `trycell()` call returns 1, then there was a solution and we can return 1 to indicate there was a solution (all the board entries will be filled in at this point).  Otherwise, we try the next number.

Comment: Perfect well explained, just a query most this part that does exactly

Comment: if (!(used & 1) && trycell(x, pos + 1))

Comment: thanks friend for taking the time to answer my questions